# В чем ошибка в коде ? Уменьшение фона при скроллинге

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1000) {
    $('img').addClass("scroll");
  } else {
    $('img').removeClass("scroll");
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
}

body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 1670px;
}

.header {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.header>img {
  margin-top: -20%;
  margin-left: 140px;
  max-width: 200%;
  width: 150%;
  /*  transform: scaleX() */
}

.header.scroll>img {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyfjp.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Во-первых, где в коде фон? Во-вторых, вы добавляете для `img` класс `scroll`, но никаких стилей для `img.scroll` у вас нет — неудивительно, что ничего не меняется

Comment: Понял ошибку спасибо.

Comment: Не плохо было бы подробнее описать желаемый конечный результат

Comment: И еще не верно описана последовательность селектора.   ***script*** добавляет и удаляет `class scroll` элементу `img`, а в стилях прописано, что `.header.scroll>img {`  что `class scroll` принадлежит  `header`..  в стилях должно быть `.header > img.scroll {`